# to read from a text file 4 lines or several lines at a time

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to write a code for a cellphone register on python. I'm suppose to read diffrent contacts from a text file. Every contact person on the list takes about 4 lines, I tried to read one line at a time(it works), But I wonder if there is easier way, for example to read 4 lines directly och creat an object list or a list, is it possible? if it is how?

Comment: You can use `for each in range(4):` and then read those four lines that way

Comment: Can you explain more?, that would be nice :)

Comment: Would it help if I showed you a code I made? The code is supposed to be able to read and write files, and allow users to edit files.

Comment: And `for each in range(4):` will run the following code four times, with the following code being reading the file

Comment: yes! that would help me visualize it and understand it more :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'about 4 lines', but here's a start:

```
with open('thefile.txt') as infile:
    while True:
        parts = [infile.readline() for _ in range(4)]
        if not any(parts):
            break
        part1, part2, part3, part4 = parts
```

Comment: for example, a contact can look like this in the text file 
surname
forename
phone number
Address

all those four lines above describes a person

Answer (score 0):

Assume the file you try to read is contacts.txt and it's at current path

```
      with open('contacts.txt','r') as f:
           lines = f.readlines()
      for i in xrange(0,len(lines),4):
           contact_source = lines[0:i]
           BuildObject(contact_source)
```

Comment: for i in xrange(0,len(lines),4): 
what does x imply?

Comment: in python 2.x   xrange is a generator compared to range creating a list, which is more efficient (space-wise) to use in for loop.  Functionality-wise, xrange() is equivatlent to range()

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly use a generator function like this (You don't need to read the entire file initially here),

```
def multilinefile(fn, no_lns):
    f, lines = open(fn), []
    while '' not in lines:
        lines = map(lambda s: f.readline(), range(no_lns))
        if lines[0] == '':
            break
        yield ''.join(lines)

for line in multilinefile(your_file, 4):
    print line
```